# Pyspark remove duplicates based on string value from another columns

Tags: pyspark

I have this dataframe below:

```
+--------+----------+----------+
|SID     |Date      |Attribute |
+--------+----------+----------+
|1001    |2021-01-01|Y         |
|1001    |2021-05-31|N         |
|1001    |2021-05-15|N         |
|1002    |2021-05-31|N         |
|1002    |2021-04-06|N         |
|1003    |2021-01-01|Y         |
|1003    |2021-02-01|N         |
|1004    |2021-03-30|N         |
+--------+----------+----------+
```

I'm trying to get the result like below.

```
+--------+----------+----------+
|SID     |Date      |Attribute |
+--------+----------+----------+
|1001    |2021-01-01|Y         |
|1002    |2021-05-31|N         |
|1002    |2021-04-06|N         |
|1003    |2021-01-01|Y         |
|1004    |2021-03-30|N         |
+--------+----------+----------+
```

I want to exclude the record when a duplicate `SID` has `Y` in one its row for `Attribute` but keep the records for `SID` if there's only `N` in the `Attribute`.

I think window partition with filter can help but I'm not sure how to do it with the conditions I mentioned. Is there any way this can be achieved in Pyspark? I saw a similar post but it was for Scala SQL and not for Pyspark.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


#Create a window of each group ordered by Date and containing all elements in a specified column
h = Window.partitionBy('SID').orderBy('Date').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

(
 # Create a column in which you broadcast first Attribute value in each SID
 df.withColumn('filt', F.first('Attribute').over(h))
 
 # After broadcast, filter where Attribute value equals to the new columns value and drop the new column
 .filter(F.col('Attribute') == F.col('filt')).drop('filt')
).show()


+----+----------+---------+
| SID|      Date|Attribute|
+----+----------+---------+
|1001|2021-01-01|        Y|
|1002|2021-04-06|        N|
|1002|2021-05-31|        N|
|1003|2021-01-01|        Y|
|1004|2021-03-30|        N|
+----+----------+---------+
```